How to choose the parts for this LM2596S-5 buck converter?
I am using the LM2596S-5 buck converter with a +12V input from a Turnigy Nano-Tech 2200mAh 3S 25C LiPo battery (with an XT60 connector). My goal is to achieve a 5V output with a maximum current of 2500mA. I have reviewed the datasheet but am having trouble selecting appropriate components for C15, C20, and L3. What would be the recommended components?


For a battery-powered application, if "long-lasting" is something you are afraid of then LM2596S wouldn't be a good choice because of its low efficiency. If it's not too late or if it's not that you have to use that IC, consider other ICs such as LMR51430 (sync-buck). Other than that, you can use WEBENCH as a starting point. I just tried it and it gave me quite similar results.

There is no need to ask people here for recommendation for components. This product is also made by Texas Instruments. TI offers full (and free) automated assistance with design of their products.
The algorithm is as follows:

Google the part (LM2596S-5), select the link from TI (or go to TI.com, search for LM2596S, select "datasheet, information, and support);
Select "Design and Development" tab;
Scroll down to "WEBBENCH(R) Designer" area;
Click on [open design];
Log into TI account (or register for a new one);
Select desired parameters for your converter;
Check input-output parameters for the automatically generated design, inspect charts etc.;
Go to "Bill of Materials"
If you don't like the suggested components (manufacturer or price), you can select an alternative part;
You can export the TI web schematics into 6 different design tools;
Most important: follow PCB layout recommendations with regard to "high-current loops", "copy exactly" is a preferred way.

That's it, this will give you the most professional and validated "opinion".
P.S. The WEBBENCH designer also can offer you alternative designs with newer parts, you can choose various optimizations for cost, efficiency, or smallest PCB area.

Thank you! I just found that out after I asked the question.

Since it is powered by battery a high 680uF capacitor at input is not required unless you have long (more than 50cm) cable between battery and circuit, can be small down to 10uF or so (680uF will not have bad effect anyway). I advise you to put a 01..1uF ceramic capacitor as close as possible to the chip.
It is a high frequency switching regulator. PWM period is 6.7us, on 220uF output with 3A current drawn at worst case 90mA ripple will occur. It will be your decision to accept it or use a higher capacitor at output. In reality for your case ripple will be about half of this calculated value.
At 3A delta current thru 33uH inductor at each pulse will be maximum 1.4A, so this will work in continuous current mode. Remaining 1.6A is constant DC thru it. It is important the inductor not saturate with that current. In reality pulsed current will not exceed 0.6A.
1N5824 is obsolete but still a good 5A diode that can be used.
I expect no problem with this chip.
